# $\int_1^2 \operatorname{cosec}^2 4t\; dt $ Evaluate this definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_1^2 \operatorname{cosec}^2 4 t\;dt$$

Been trying to evalute this definite integral, although I can't find what $\operatorname{cosec}^2$ is?

Comment: do you meant $$\int_{1}^{2}\ csc^2(4x)dx$$?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure how to make the symbol

Comment: For future reference, @joe, you need to use **backslashes** not **forward slashes** when typing these commands.

Comment: $\int_1^2$ is this how?

Comment: or $\operatorname{cosec}{x}=$

Comment: Also, $\operatorname{cosec} x \equiv \frac 1  {\sin x} $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, 
$$\int_{1}^{2}\csc^24t dt$$
Let, $4t=u\iff 4dt=du\iff dt=\frac{du}{4}$

Now, we have 
$$\int_{4}^{8}\csc^2(u) \frac{du}{4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}\int_{4}^{8}\csc^2(u) du$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\left[-\cot u\right]_{4}^{8}$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}\left[-\cot 8+\cot 4\right]$$ $$=\frac{1}{4}\left[\cot 4-\cot 8\right]$$

Comment: so the integral of cosec^2 is -cot?

Comment: Yes you are right, Since $$\frac{d}{dx}(\cot x)=-\csc^2 x$$

Comment: and the 1/4? probably asking really obvious questions here, i'm a bit rusty on this

Comment: OK, you can let $4t=x\iff 4dt=dx\iff dt=\frac{1}{4}dx$ Substitute this & find the integral you will get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\csc^{2n+2}\theta\ d\theta=\int\text{cosec}^{2n+2}\theta\ d\theta=\int(1+\cot^2\theta)^n\ \text{cosec}^2\theta\ d\theta$$

Set $\cot\theta=y$

Comment: i'm not sure whats going on here??

Comment: @joe, $\csc$ is also written as cosec